# on_member_update nickname change doesn't work out as intended

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was trying to set events for my bot, however, it always returns this error after trying to edit the nickname on my server:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, ctx, member_before, member_after):
        nickname_after = f"{member_after.nickname}" if not member_after.nickname else member_after.nickname
        nickname_before = f"{member_before.nickname}" if not member_before.nickname else member_before.nickname
        embed = discord.Embed(timestamp = ctx.message.created_at , color = discord.Colour.random() ,
                              title = "Member Update")
        embed.add_field(name = "Nickname before:" , value = f"{nickname_before}" , inline = True)
        embed.add_field(name = "Nickname after:" , value = f"{nickname_after}" , inline = True)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url = f"{member_after.avatar.url}")
        embed.set_author(name = f"{self.osamu.user}" , icon_url = f"{self.osamu.avatar.url}")
        channel = self.osamu.get_channel(898199584726188042)
        return await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

The following traceback has been detected:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ohnezahn/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 352, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member_after'
```

What I'm trying to achieve: if the user is editing his nickname the bot shall send the embed in the Channel which I've set (`channel = self.osamu.get_channel(898199584726188042)`). However, the response is the traceback, no embed whatsoever...

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, `on_member_update` only takes 2 parameters: `before` and `after`. Since your listener seems to be in a class you also need to use `self` as the first argument.

So if you remove the `ctx` from your arguments it should work properly.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, member_before, member_after):
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update